# Routing Error : ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: routes, .net-core-3.1

I have an routing error since we have migrating from .netCore 2.1 to 3.1.

Here are some explanations :
In a web application, in the startup.cs, we have 2 routes like this :

```
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "MyCustomRoute1",
      pattern: "MyPath/{slug}/m{id1}s{id2}", //MyPath/my-slug/m38s1
      defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index" },
      constraints: new { slug = "[a-z-]+", id1 = "[0-9]+", id2 = "[0-9]+" });

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "MyCustomRoute2",
      pattern: "MyPath/{slug}/s{id1}", //MyPath/my-slug/s1
      defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "Index" },
      constraints: new { slug = "[a-z-]+", id1 = "[0-9]+" });
```

When I launch this URL https://localhost:44300/MyPath/my-slug/m38s1 I
have no error and `MyCustomRoute1` is used.

When I launch this URL https://localhost:44300/MyPath/my-slug/s1, the route `MyCustomRoute2` should be used. But I have this error :

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
System.ReadOnlySpan<T>.Slice(int start, int length)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RoutePatternMatcher.MatchComplexSegmentCore(RoutePatternPathSegment routeSegment, ReadOnlySpan<char> requestSegment, RouteValueDictionary values, int indexOfLastSegmentUsed)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RoutePatternMatcher.MatchComplexSegment(RoutePatternPathSegment routeSegment, ReadOnlySpan<char> requestSegment, RouteValueDictionary values)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.ProcessComplexSegments(Endpoint endpoint, ValueTuple<RoutePatternPathSegment, int>[] complexSegments, string path, ReadOnlySpan<PathSegment> segments, RouteValueDictionary values)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I think that the routing engine chose the wrong route (`MyCustomRoute1` instead of `MyCustomRoute2`) and cannot create routeData

These configuration work fine on .netCore 2.1 but not in .netCore 3.1. I also try in .Net5 : this is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in .NET with the `RoutePatternMatcher`:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/44674

In the description it says:

> This happens when we try to match complex segment consisting of at
> least 2 parameters prefixed by a literal (example ".{b}-{c}") to a
> path that begins with the literal prefixing the last parameter in the
> segment (example "-hello").

I am experiencing this error with URL paths starting with a dot (e.g. `example.org/.xml`). Annoyingly this also occurs when bots try out URLs that do not exist.

This should be fixed with .NET 8 when it comes out.